# Auto space children of fixed-width LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a row of text that I use a `LinearLayout` to represent:

```xml
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="D"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="F"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="G"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I want these letters to be equally spaced in the `LinearLayout` (sort of like the `auto` margin in `CSS`); right now they just all sort of bunch together. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily accomplished by setting the `layout_width` of the `LinearLayout` to `0dp` and the `layout_weight` of each `TextView` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="A"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="B"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="C"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="D"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="E"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="F"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="G"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I suggest use Horizontal scroll view as parent for left to right scroll